# Fermi-Surfaces of Alkali-Metals

Tags: solid-state-physics, fermi-energy

I think I am a bit confused if I look at the following image of Fermi-surfaces for different metals: [image]

Li, Na, K, Rb and Cs have only one valence electron. Hence, if one calculates the Fermi-vector $k_F$, it is the same for all those metals, isn't it? But then, why does it in the case of Cs overlap with the boundary zone of the 1st Brillouin zone?

Comment: Because they aren't completely free electrons. So, the Fermi surface is not a perfect sphere. For the lighter alkali metals it comes pretty close, sure, but that is all.

Comment: The answer (mine) to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57484/why-alkali-metals-have-bcc-structure/57599#57599 has info that may be useful.